# AWS RDS Oracle Datapump error ORA-39001: invalid argument value

Tags: oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I want to import my dump file from my local to AWS. I've uploaded my `pdv.dpdm` file into my S3 bucket

```
expdp sys/pass schemas=PDV dumpfile=pdv.dpdm NOLOGFILE=YES directory=TEST_DIR
```

I was success downloading that file into oracle `DATA_PUMP_DIR` with `rdsadmin.rdsadmin_s3_tasks.download_from_s3` command, When I list the files inside that directory, I got this. So I think the problem is not the failure when moving the data.

```
select * from table
(rdsadmin.rds_file_util.listdir(p_directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR'));

datapump/   directory   4096    2020-03-04 06:49:40
pdv2.log    file    28411   2020-03-04 06:49:40
29012020.DMP    file    825552896   2020-03-03 09:36:59
pdv2.dpdm   file    685617152   2020-03-04 06:49:40
pdv.dpdm    file    685613056   2020-03-04 06:49:27
```

When I starting to import that file with `DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE` I got an error on that line.

```
DECLARE
hdnl NUMBER;
BEGIN
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=> NULL, version => 12);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.ADD_FILE( 
    handle => hdnl, 
    filename => 'pdv.dpdm', 
    directory => 'DATA_PUMP_DIR',
    filetype => DBMS_DATAPUMP.KU$_FILE_TYPE_DUMP_FILE
);
DBMS_DATAPUMP.START_JOB(hdnl);
END;

Error :

SQL Error [39001] [99999]: ORA-39001: invalid argument value
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 79
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4087
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_DATAPUMP", line 4338
ORA-06512: at line 6
```

It seems I'm missing something, maybe configure in AWS or what. I've done searching for a couple of answers but it doesn't fix my problem. Could you help me with this? I don't know anymore what should I do. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are mistaken with the import version.

```
hdnl := DBMS_DATAPUMP.OPEN( operation => 'IMPORT', job_mode => 'SCHEMA', job_name=> NULL, version => 12);
```

**version=>'12.0.0'**

[Oracle Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_datpmp.htm#ARPLS66053)

> COMPATIBLE - (default) the version of the metadata corresponds to the
>   database compatibility level and the compatibility release level for
>   feature (as given in the V$COMPATIBILITY view). Database compatibility
>   must be set to 9.2 or higher.
>
> LATEST - the version of the metadata corresponds to the database
>   version.
>
> A specific database version, for example, '11.0.0'.
>
> Specify a value of 12 to allow all existing database features,
>   components, and options to be exported from Oracle Database 11g
>   release 2 (11.2.0.3) or later into an Oracle Database 12 c Release 1
>   (12.1) (either a multitenant container database (CDB) or a non-CDB).

You must export as a non-SYS user!

```
grant read, write on directory TEST_DIR to PDV;

expdp PDV/password schemas=PDV dumpfile=pdv.dpdm NOLOGFILE=YES directory=TEST_DIR
```

[Oracle Documentation](http://%20%20[1]:%20https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sutil/oracle-data-pump-export-utility.html#GUID-D5455260-C28C-475F-9E0E-2BE227E7F0E3)

> Note:Do not start Export as SYSDBA, except at the request of Oracle
>   technical support. SYSDBA is used internally and has specialized
>   functions; its behavior is not the same as for general users.